# How to make posts being uncategorized

Tags: posts, categories

I have some posts which do not have any category, by default, wordpress shows them under "Un categorized". Is there any way to stop this? I want those posts under the categories I have in **metabox title**  (list of categories for meta tag, if I select some category, from metabox title, it should come under the selected categories from metabox title). But it saves the posts under "Un categorized"

Comment: What code are you using to generate the metabox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All posts have to be associated with at least one category. It might be possible to bypass this requirement but probably doesn't worth the effort.

If you really need to be able to have content without categories then you should create and use a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), with which you can create and use [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies). It is hard to understand from the question what are you doing with the meta values but it sounds like you are trying to recreate the functionality of custom taxonomies.

Comment: Or simply rename `Uncategorized` to `Categorized` (or whatever fits) ;)

Comment: My impression is that OP doesn't want to use categories at all but rather an alternative categorizing system

Comment: Yep, agreed, but the Q is badly formulated. I'd suggest that you add *Custom Taxonomy* to the Answer as well. Linking to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) makes the *A* more complete. Just realized that almost never I put a summary when linking to the Codex, but maybe it'd be nice too.

Comment: ok, added some links. I don't think you can summarize CPT and custom taxonomies without copying the codex...

Comment: No prob, I should've encapsulated my comment with `<opinion>the_comment();</opinion>` ;)